# array creation filtered by data arrived from xml (filter and matrix)

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with creation of an array filtered. I have a variable called _xData that is a group of data; I do for cycle to see all rows of my variable and log is similar to this:

- {IdQuiz: "1", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "2", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "3", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- IdQuiz: "4", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "5", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "6", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "7", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "8", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "9", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}...

this log continues for 1545 rows.

I do this to filter an array in which there are three rows with same "Blocco",

I tried like this but I only got the first occurrence:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < _xData.length; i++) {
        blocco = _xData[i].Blocco;
        console.log(_xData[i]);
        if (blocco == _xData[k].Blocco) {
            //console.log(_xData[i]);
            tot = array.push(_xData[i]);

        }
    }console.log("ARRAY =", array);
```

in this log I got:

- {IdQuiz: "1", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "2", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}
- {IdQuiz: "3", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00", …}

How can I get all the arrays (545) already divided into triplets and filtered by "Blocco"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const _xData = [
    { IdQuiz: "1", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "2", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "3", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "4", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "5", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "6", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "7", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "8", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
    { IdQuiz: "9", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" }
];

const array = Object.values(_xData.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc[cur.Blocco]) {
        acc[cur.Blocco].push(cur);
    } else {
        acc[cur.Blocco] = [cur];
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log("ARRAY =", array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MAN!! U save me!

Answer (score 2):

You can get your desired result like this

```js
const groupBy = function(array, key) {
  return array.reduce(function(accumulator, item) {
    const groupValue = item[key];
    accumulator[groupValue] = accumulator[groupValue] || [];
    accumulator[groupValue].push(item);
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
};

const _xData = [
  { IdQuiz: "1", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "2", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "3", Blocco: "00451", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "4", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "5", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "6", Blocco: "00450", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "7", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "01", Risposta: "TRUE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "8", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "02", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" },
  { IdQuiz: "9", Blocco: "00452", Domanda: "03", Risposta: "FALSE", Capitolo: "00" }
];

const result = Object.values(groupBy(_xData, 'Blocco'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: no,now i want a monodimensional array but with change position at group of 3 with same .Blocco!

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn my triplets 20 times, but I would like to check, that is, that I extract without repetitions! ideas ??

this is my code:

```
var bacino = new Array(20);
var index;
var domanda;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    index = (Math.round((Math.random() * 514) + 1));
    bacino[i] = bacino.push(array[index]);
    bacino[i] = bacino.pop();
}
```

Comment: no,now i want a monodimensional array but with change position at group of 3 with same .Blocco! –

i want a mono-array with change position of data!!!